# Twitter Widget "Event" in HTML inspector disappearing when styles overriden

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on custom styling of the default Twitter widget (the one you can embed on your website. I've figured out the injection of the styles and it works great, but I've recently realized that when my styles are injected you can no longer click on the Tweet to open it in a new page.
I'm injecting style like that:

```
const iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
const injectedStyle = `<style>${css}</style>`;
iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = iframeDocument.body.innerHTML + injectedStyle;
```

I had to do it that way because passing `<link>` with .css file doesn't work here. When the code above is executed, in Firefox Inspector I can see that "Event" disappears - I'd like to know why is that happening, and if it is possible to inject my style AND have clickable Tweets.

[image: When no styles injected]

[image: When style injected]

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. The problem was that I was appending my custom styling to the body, and not the head. When I've used `iframeDocument.head.innerHTML =  iframeDocument.head.innerHTML + injectedStyle;` it started to work just fine.